# As of Rails 4.0, is this still the best way to protect against MYSQL injection attacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Here I'm simply using a substitution character, and sending active record the array.

```
string_one = Ryan
string_two = Smith

@x = Client.find(:all, conditions: [“first_name: ?, last_name = ?”, string_one, string_two ])
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "rails attack"?

Comment: I meant MYSQL injection!

Comment: I think the Client.find(:all, :conditions...) is deprecated AR in Rails 4, but still safe against attacks.  The preferred scheme is chained methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically see syntax like this in Rails 3 and 4:

```
@x = Client.where(first_name: string_one, last_name: string_two)
```

If you need to do more complex `WHERE` filters than `x = ? AND y = ?`, then the parameterized strings are usually coded like this:

```
@x = Client.where('birthdate > ? OR birthdate IS NULL', 21.years.ago)
```

But yes, the syntax you provide in your question is safe from SQL injection, as is the syntax provided in this answer.

Comment: In the second example, how would you pass variables into the query?

Comment: You pass the variables as additional arguments. The `21.years.ago` was an example of that, which gets used in the `?` placeholder. Sorry, that could have been clearer, I suppose. :)

Comment: No problem! But maybe amend answer for future viewers?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you use the ActiveRecord functions for supplying parameters, you're well protected against SQL injection attacks.  ex.

```
@x = Client.find(:all, conditions: [“first_name: ?, last_name = ?”, 
                  string_one, string_two ])
```

The Client#find will correctly quote the values of string_one to prevent (unintentional or malicious) manipulation of the actual SQL sent to the DB.  This is true for most ORM and parameterization mechanisms.

Where you can get into trouble is building raw SQL like this:

```
@x = Client.find_by_sql("SELECT foo WHERE first_name=#{string_one}")
```

In this case, 'string_one' can contain arbitrary SQL.  When you build raw SQL like this you have to be careful to protect against this; there's an #sanitize method to help.